# Having trouble in accessing posted form data (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

### How to access posted form data in action method and display in view

I'm creating an input wizard in MVC. There are two views, one for taking input from user and another for display the input data.

Here is the model's code:

```
 public class Info
  {
    public int CustomerId { set; get; }
    public double Price { set; get; }
    public string name { set; get; }
  }
}
```

Controller's Code-

```
    public ActionResult FillCustomer()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult DisplayCustomer(FormCollection frm)
    {
        Info info = new Info();

        info.name = Convert.ToString( Request.Form["name"]);
        info.Price = Convert.ToDouble(Request.Form["price"]);
        info.CustomerId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["customerid"]);

        return View(info);
    }
```

FillCustomer View's Code-

```
<form method="post" action="DisplayCustomer">
Name: <input type="text" id="name" /><br />
Price: <input type="text" id="price" /><br />
CustomerId: <input type="text" id="customerid" />
<br />
<input type="submit" id="btn1" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

DisplayCustomer View's Code-

```
<body>
<div>
Name is <%=Model.name %> and ID is <%=Model.CustomerId %>

<%if (Model.Price > 200)
  {%>

Greater than 200

<%}
  else %>

<%{%>Lesser than 200 

    <%} %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I checked with debugger, controller is not getting posted data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form's input elements should have a **name** attribute

```
<form method="post" action="DisplayCustomer">
Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name" /><br />
Price: <input type="text" id="price" name="price" /><br />
CustomerId: <input type="text" id="customerid" name="customerid" />
<br />
<input type="submit" id="btn1" />
</form>
```

Now you will get form data as

```
        Info info = new Info();
        info.name = Convert.ToString( Request.Form["name"]);
        info.Price = Convert.ToDouble(Request.Form["price"]);
        info.CustomerId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["customerid"]);
```

*In controller, form data is received as key/value pairs. And keys are generaetd from name attributes.*

Answer (score 1):

You are using MVC so the parameter in DisplayCustomer method is your model passed from view, which is created implicitly by model binder. Change the type from FormCollection to Info class as following:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult DisplayCustomer(Info model)
{
   // you can now access to Info properties
}
```

This way values of Info object are populeted and I think this is what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed to write a Attribute top of the DisplayCustomer function. Just write it, I hope it will work.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult DisplayCustomer(FormCollection frm)
{
    Info info = new Info();

    info.name = Convert.ToString( Request.Form["name"]);
    info.Price = Convert.ToDouble(Request.Form["price"]);
    info.CustomerId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["customerid"]);

    return View(info);
}
```

Comment: I have checked by putting these attributes. But still it's not getting posted data.